# Raspberry Pi getting same IP

Tags: ip, raspberry-pi, nginx

So I connected my Raspberry Pi ( with Raspbian on it ) to my router to give it an internet connection for it's own, then I added an ACCEPT rule in iptables on port 80 and started up nginx. I used lynx to get response from whatsmyip.org to check the Pi's IP address then I tried to connect to the nginx server using my phone and the external IP in a browser, this one timed out though.

So I went to check out what was wrong and noticed my laptop(where im on now) is assigned the external IP Address as my Raspberry Pi ( atleast, whatsmyip.org showed the same addresses for the pi and my laptop individually), how can I make sure the Pi get's it's own external IP so I can connect to the webhost?

Note: Every communication/things done on the Pi are done by using putty for SSH via my laptop and the Pi's internal IP, perhaps this has something to do with it?

Comment: All your internet connections in your house will have a single external IP, use port forwarding on your router to point traffic on port 80 to your Pi. There is no need for another external IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find out the MAC address of your Pi, then assign a static IP address to it on your router's admin page (on TP-Link routers it's under the DHCP menu). Then use port forwarding to redirect port 80 to the IP you assigned to your Pi.